# drop condition in pdf

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider the following equation to hold for the conditional pdfs of random variables $A,B,C$:

$p(A|B,C) = p(A|B)$ (1).

Certainly: $C$ being independent of both $A$ and $B$ implies (1) to hold.

But does also (1) imply that $C$ is independent of $A$ and $B$, so is it equivalence? Or under which circumstances are the two equivalent?

If I apply Bayes i get
$\frac{p(B,C|A)p(A)}{p(B,C)} = \frac{p(B|A)p(A)}{p(B)}$ (1')

This looks like I would need also $B$ to be independent of $C$ so that $p(B)p(C) = p(B,C)$ and the denominator would be the same after expansion with $p(B)$. ...

---

To state my problem more clearly.

**I.** It seems to me that

$\frac{p(B,C|A)p(A)}{p(B,C)} \neq \frac{p(B|A)p(A)}{p(B)}$ $\implies$ $p(B,C|A) \neq p(B|A)p(C)$ **or** $p(B,C) \neq p(B)p(C)$.

Which again implies

$B$ and $C$ are not conditionally independent given $A$
**or**
$B$ and $C$ are not conditionally independent.
**or**
$C$ not independent of $A$

(It is: $B$ and $C$ independent and $A$ and $C$ independent $\implies$ equality and by Bayes $p(A|B,C) = p(A|B)$)

**II.** Whereas

$p(A|B,C) \neq p(A|B)$ seems to imply definitely that $C$ and $A$ are not independent.

(It is: $C$ independent $A$ $\implies p(A|B,C) = p(A|B)$)

This seems somehow puzzling as those unequalities can be transormed into one anoter by bayes...

---

More precise, if

(1) $p(A|B,C) \neq p(A|B) \implies$ $C$ not independent of $A$ or $C$ not independent of $B$.

(2) $C$ independent of $A \implies p(A|B,C) = p(A|B)$

then there is something wrong. But both (1) and (2) seem to be true considering above thoughts.

Comment: If we have $p(A|B,C) \neq p(A|B)$ what can we say about $A,B,C$? Only that $C$ is not independent of $A$ or other things?

Comment: I edited my question so that it contains what makes me wonder. If I apply Bayes, it seems that I would need $C$ to be independent of both $A$ and $B$..

Comment: Ok, I will think over it

Answer (score 0):

Property (1) means that the process $C\to B\to A$ is a Markov chain. Let property (2) be that $C$ is independent of $(A,B)$. Then (2) implies (1) but (1) does not imply (2). Counterexample: $B=C$. On the other hand, if (1) holds and if $B$ and $C$ are independent then (2) holds.